# Asking for some help in proof of the properties of a special type of metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space such that $d(x,z)\le \max\{d(y,z),d(x,y)\} , \forall x,y,z \in X$ , then is every

ball in $X$  both closed and open i.e. is every open ball closed and every closed ball is open  ?

and also is it true that For any $x,y\in X $ and $r,s>0$ ,

$B(x,r) \cap B(y,s)=\phi \implies B(x,r) \subseteq B(y,s)$ or$B(y,s) \subseteq B(x,r)$ ?

What I only know about such metric spaces is that , for any $x,y \in X$ , $r>0$ , $d(x,y)<r \implies B(x,r)=B(y,r) $  , but nothing else , please help .

Answer (score 1):

The spaces you are considering are called ultra-metric spaces.

Indeed every closed ball $B[x,r]=\{y\in X : d(x,y)\leq r\}$ is open: Since $B(x,r)\subseteq B[x,r]$ and $B(x,r)$ is open, we only need to show that for every $y\in B[x,r]$ with $d(x,y)=r$ there exists $B(y,s)\subseteq B[x,r]$. Take any $s\leq r$ and $z\in B(y,s)$. Then

$d(x,z)\leq\max (d(x,y),d(y,z))\leq r$,

hence $z\in B[x,r]$ and thus $B(y,s)\subseteq B[x,r]$ as desired.

Also every open ball $B(x,r)$ is closed: To this end take a sequence $(x_k)$ in $B(x,r)$ that converges to $x_0\in X$. Then there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_k,x_0)<r$ for all $k>n$. Consequently

$d(x,x_0)\leq\max (d(x,x_k),d(x_k,x_0))<r$

for every $k>n$, that is $x_0\in B(x,r)$. So every limit of a converging sequence in $B(x,r)$ lies in $B(x,r)$ too, which gives the assertion.